# shiny dashboard : create a table of contents inside a sidebar

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, sidebar

I am creating a shiny app and I want to create a dashboard.

I want to customize the sidebarmenu, I already create menuitems but I am searching to add the titles of the boxes below the title of the menuitem, like a table of contents. The submenuitem is not an answer for my problem.
Is so that the user can navigate more easily in the page.

I don't know how to provide my code, my question is general.

Thanks for your help, and sorry for my english.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.